# Display UML classes alphabetically in Diagrams.net?

Tags: uml, metadata, draw.io, diagrams.net

In Diagrams.net, is there any way to display (and edit) the metadata of UML classes ***as an alphabetical list***? - This could for example be a useful way to create a glossary of UML classes to complement the diagram (especially for very large UML structures).

It could also make it a lot easier to edit the metadata of classes, without having to first locate each class in the diagram before editing the metadata?

Is there a solution to this problem?

I have tried extensive internet searching for solutions.